# How to handle hourly Bigtable connection closes?

Tags: go, grpc, google-cloud-bigtable

I have golang services with persistant Bigtable client.
The services are making hundred of read/write operation on Bigtable per sec.

Every hours from the service boot, I experience hundred of errors like this one:

```
Retryable error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc =
 the connection is draining, retrying in 74.49241ms
```

The error are followed by an increased processing time I can't allow when thoses errors occur.

I was able to figure out that Bigtable client is using a pool of gRPC connections.

It seems that Bigtable gRPC server have a connection maxAge of 1 hour which can explain the error above and the processing time increasing during reconnection.

A maxAgeGrace configuration is supposed to give additional time to complete current operations and avoid all pool connections to terminate at the same time.

I increased connection pool size from default 4 to 12 with no real benefit

How do I prevent processing time to increase during reconnections and these error to happen, given my traffic will keep growing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud bigtable clients use a pool of gRPC connections to connect to bigtable. Java client uses a channel pool per HBase connection, each channel pool has multiple gRPC connections. gRPC connections are shut down every hour (or after 15 minute of inactivity) and the underlying gRPC infrastructure performs a reconnect. The first request on each new connection performs a number of setup tasks such as TLS handshakes and warming server side caches. These operations are fairly expensive and may cause the latency spikes.

Bigtable is designed to be a high throughput system and the amortized cost of these reconnections with sustained query volume should be negligible. However, if the client application has very low QPS or long periods of idle time between queries and can not tolerate these latency spikes, it can create a new Hbase connection(java) or a new CBT client(golang) every 30-40 minutes and run no op calls (exist on hbase client or read a small row)  on the new connection/client to prime the underlying gRPC connections (one call per connection, for hbase default is twice the number of CPUs, go has 4 connections by default). Once primed you can swap out the new connection/client for the main operations in the client application. [Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/go/connection-refresh) is sample go code for this workaround.

Comment: The workaround code you linked leverages a "rotating table" concept and notes "A new table reference will need to have some requests go across it to establish each connection in the connection pool". Does that mean when a new Bigtable client is being setup, each table opened in the client application must be resaturated? Or the new Bigtable client can just leverage a single table to prime the underlying gRPC connections?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this may be due to a [bug](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/2663) that gets introduced in a recent grpc-go release, and just got [fixed](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/pull/2669). Basically, instead of reconnecting immediately when a connection goes away, we incorrectly wait 1s before reconnecting. Please try again with grpc-go master head. Thanks!